# Specifying a set of prioritized namespaces for finding API controllers?

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5

**Fact:** the current VS.2015 templates the authorization implementation differs dramatically between a WebAPI project and an MVC project.
**Fact:** My project has both MVC and WebAPI 2.0 components
**Requirement:** Identity 2.0 authorization for both WebAPI and MVC controllers
**Wish:** I want both controllers to be named Account but one in the Controllers namespace and the other in Controllers.Api, thus avoid renaming one of the controllers.

knowing that and that apparently the only way is to merge both Identity/Authorization implementations into one project, it would mean I need two account controllers and two sets of account-related models.

In the MVC MapRoute (RouteConfig.cs) one can specify the namespaces for the MVC controllers. But since I am going to have two account controllers (one for API the other for MVC) I plan to put the API Account controller in MyNamespace.Controllers.Api and leave the MVC on MyNamespace.Controllers. But On the WebApiConfig.cs file the HttpRoute method seems to have no parameter to configure the namespace, that means it would find the AccountController used in MVC rather than the one it needs isn the .Api subnamespace.

Is there a way to tell the WebAPI route to look for its controllers in the Controllers.Api namespace rather than the Controllers namespace?

As I stated, I do not want to rename one of the controllers unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Did you manage to achive this?  Looks like it isn't possible?

Comment: @AlanMacdonald I merged both templates but that is not optimal. Also the WebAPI account features appear to be largely undocumented.